# 1 processes and 0 service under Settings, Apps and Running

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-service

The application is working, but why is the service not showing up?

What is the cause of the problem, given that the Android version 10

**Edit**

has been added

super.onCreate();

I used notifications, but the problem didn't work

I haven't been able to identify the cause of the problem yet

[image]
**in manifest
**

```
<service
            android:name=".Service.AlarmService"
            android:label="Alarm"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"/>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**in service**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    IBinder iBinder;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);


    }

   

     @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
              player =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ringtone);
    
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startMyOwnForeground();
    else
                startForeground(1, new Notification());
        }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();


       // bettrylife(this);
       // stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return iBinder;
    }
    private void bettrylife(Context context){
        PackageManager manager= context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, AlarmService.class);

        int settingcode =PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,settingcode, DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
 

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private void startMyOwnForeground()
        {
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
            String channelName = "Background Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
    
    
    }
```

**in fragment**

```
Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),AlarmService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Your `startForegroundService()` call will not work, as you are not calling `startForeground()` from inside the service. You also are not calling through to `super.onCreate()` from your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: It didn't work, I did everything

Comment: Then perhaps you should update your question to show your code that uses `startForeground()` and `super.onCreate()`. Perhaps there is a bug tied to those that we can identify.

Comment: I have modified

Answer (score 0):

When working with foreground services in Android, it's a requirement to call startForeground() within the onStartCommand() method to provide a persistent notification to the user. This notification informs the user that your app is running a foreground service and helps prevent the system from terminating the service unexpectedly.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ringtone);
player.start();

// Create a notification for the foreground service
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
    .setContentText("Service is running...")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_example)
    .build();

// Start the service as a foreground service
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

return START_NOT_STICKY;
```

}

Comment: I have modified ,reconsidering

Answer (score 0):

There can be various causes that your service is not working

1. Insure that you are starting the service like startForegroundService
2. Make sure to grant the Battery Optimization permission.
3. It's possible that service instantiated but it might be getting halted and problem can be originate other side of your project.